# Encrypt files using gpg (and them symetric encrypting the key) - is it a normal thing to do in the *nix world?

Tags: security, backup, encryption, gpg

I read a lot of articles about using gpg to encrypt email, but I would like to use it to encrypt some files - mainly a bunch of *.isos. I'm going to describe what I thought I would do, so you can shoot me or just add some suggestions.

I'm going to do

```
tar -cvjf myiso.iso.tar.bz2 myiso.iso
```

and them I plan to encrypt this myisio.tar.bz2, using a key generated by gpg (don't know exactly how to do that. I'm going to read the man page). Them, I'm going to save this generated gpg key I used for this encryption in a flash drive, and encode this key itself with a symetric key.

Is it to *insane*?

Comment: The GPG key will already be protected by a passphrase, which I guess is used to symmetrically encrypt it anyway. (But there might be legal situations that may make another round of encryption useful.)

Comment: If you might want to read the ISO "on the fly", without needing to decrypt it to a (temporary, undeletable) file, you could use a program like LUKS or Veracrypt (truecrypt-like), and squashfs decompresses on the fly too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use GPG to symmetrically encrypt a file with a passphrase (`gpg -c`). If the passphrase has enough entropy, you don't need an extra step of generating a secret key. What does “enough entropy” mean? Your encryption needs to withstand offline attacks, where the attacker can make cracking attempts as fast as his hardware allows it. With a small PC farm, the attacker might be able to make a couple hundred billion attempts per second, which is roughly 2^69 per decade. So with an entropy of 2^70 you'll be safe. That means if your passphrase consists of completely random letters (lower or upper case) and digits, it should be 12 characters long.

Now to store that passphrase, you can use GPG with its usual key pairs. Use `gpg --gen-key` to generate a key pair, and `gpg -e` to encrypt the passphrase used to encrypt the large file for one or more key pairs.

Here's a sketch on how to do the encryption (note that I avoid putting the passphrase on the command line or in the environment, so as to make sure another user can't find it by looking at the `ps` output while the command is running):

```
passphrase=$(pwgen -s 12 -1)
echo "The passphrase for myiso.iso.gpg is: $passphrase" |
gpg -e -r somebody -r somebodyelse >passphrase.gpg
echo "$passphrase" | gpg -c --passphrase-fd 3 3<&0 <myiso.iso >myiso.iso.gpg
```

and how to decrypt:

```
passphrase=$(gpg -d <passphrase.gpg)
echo "$passphrase" | gpg -d --passphrase-fd 3 3<&0 <myiso.iso.gpg >myiso.iso
```

The reason to use a passphrase (a shared secret) rather than directly encrypt is that it allows the file to be shared between several people. Only the small passphrase needs to be reencrypted if you want to add a recipient (removing a recipient only makes sense if you know the recipient hasn't had access to the plaintext and requires reencoding the ciphertext anyway).

Comment: Need to remove "e" from "-ec" otherwise you get a prompt for a user id. More details: http://superuser.com/questions/354890/how-do-i-symmetrically-encrypt-a-file-using-gpg