# Password Encryption

Tags: shell-script, shell, encryption, shell-builtin

I have a *Migrate.ksh* file, in that some passwords are available, I would like to encrypt this file in the Unix. The Passwords file being used in another script.
Can you please let me know the process and script to encrypt?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212329/hiding-password-in-shell-scripts

Comment: @statox ... There's also symmetric file encryption using `gpg -c file`  ... [This Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/encrypt-files-using-gpg-and-them-symetric-encrypting-the-key-is-it-a-normal/23922) addresses that option as well as generating a secure password.

Answer (score 1):

If you have gpg on your machine:

### Encrypting the file

```
gpg --gen-key
<choose 1>
<enter 2048 bits>
<enter 0 -- key does not expire>
<y> <enter>
"enter a user id for later like admin or your user name of choice"
<enter> o <enter>
```

then type a password accept, enter it again -- now you have a new key.

Then run

```
gpg -e Migrate.ksh
```

and use user id from earlier
Now `ls` should show you the new encrypted file `Migrate.ksh.gpg`

If you have any trouble `man gpg` or `gpg -h` can help.

### Decrypting the file

```
gpg -d FileNameEncrypted.gpg -o Newfile
```

Comment: Hello Michael. I felt really breathless after reading that. Would you like some full stops? I've got a few spare in my pocket :-O If would also be somewhat more readable if you formatted the code. Code inline is marked out with backticks. Code blocks are indented four spaces and have a blank line before and after.

Comment: While RSA is still the default choice for keys in `gpg`, Curve25519 keys are much shorter with decreased encryption and decryption times.... You can generate a Curve25519 key using the `gpg --expert --full-gen-key` command and select option **9 ECC and ECC**

Comment: Is there any benefit to creating a keypair over a password / symmetric ciper, in this single computer situation? You still have to remember a password with the keypair, plus they can be deleted/corrupted like a keyfile

Comment: @Xen2050 ... There are various use cases for keys vs. symmetric ... A particularly interesting use case for keys is to have a passphrase-less key loaded onto a physical external device, such as a smart card.  This would enable seamless and transparent decryption of files and messages as long as the physical device is connected.  In general though, passphrase-less keys are discouraged... There are important differences between passphrases and passwords.  Passphrases **are not** transmitted across a network, while passwords **are** transmitted across a network.

Comment: @RubberStamp Just seems like overkill in this situation to have a password to a key, without using the other benefits of public key cryptography. Haven't heard of the passphrase - password difference, aside from actually using more than one word in a passphrase, but password is a little more commonly known (& easier to type ;-)